# Old/new website - same category URL! What to do?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem. I bought an old domain name and I redirected all my content to it now.

So I have this category as example: http://www.formulawahad.com/category/news/ (or simply formulawahad.com/news/)

So any news link is like this: http://www.formulawahad.com/news/37329/

(My wordpress installed is not in the root - inside a folder).

Today, I got all the files from this domain which goes back to 2001. And Google found like 2000 errors. Now I want to upload them and make them available as they have a lot of backlink.

But the problem is the link of the old articles are like these:

http://www.formulawahad.com/news/090217_coulthard.htm

Or: http://www.formulawahad.com/news/080623_trulli.htm

So what do I do? create a "news" folder and place all html files in it? but then what will happen to my wordpress category formulawahad.com/news/?

I have the same problem with 2 more categories. So I need your help before I decide what to do.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: upload them to a folder like `news-archive` use a rewrite rule to match `^\/news\/(.*)\.htm$` to redirect to this new folder.

Comment: Take a look at [this .htaccess](https://gist.github.com/imme-emosol/720633) - basically you want to first check if there are static files matching the requested URL, and if there aren't then rewrite the URL to Wordpress.

Comment: ok thanks so basically I have to redirect them. OK I get that.

Actually I have a question: There's a page in my wordpress called "Kimi Raikkonen" it has some good content. But also in html version there are more information. Does Google think this is duplicate content or what exactly? the title is very similar but the content is different.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to get rid of those 2000 errors in google. In wordpress [`init()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) hook you have to make  a redirect function. In databse add a table  with  old and new url,get url and search with old url and redirect it to new one.